# how to set EditText TopMargins in dp programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, margin

In my android application I want to change the topMargin of an editText.

The thing is that I want to change it "dp" wise and not pixel wise.

I want to change only the topMaring. Leave the other as is. not set them to zeros ?

programmatically i can set margins in int only?

Answer (score 15):

set like follw code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, convertPixelsToDp(5,this), 0, 0);
editText.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

and `convert Pixels To Dp`

```
public static int convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

use follow code for changing just one.

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.topMargin = convertPixelsToDp(5,this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: and if I want to change only the topMaring. Leave the other as is. not set them to zeros ?

Comment: programmatically i can set margins in int only?

Comment: see my Edit, get your `Layout Params` and set to your `EditText`.

Comment: Yes, also found an example of this here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/packages/apps/Nfc/src/com/android/nfc/SendUi.java

Answer (score 4):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
editText.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: It would help to add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can not directly set margins using dp programmatically, because `.setMargins` method ask pixels not for dp so if you want to give dp's instead of pixels, you should convert dps to pixels. 
first create LayoutParams instance:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

then set convert dp to pixels and set margins of the layout like this:

```
lp.setMargins(left, dpToPx(30), right, bottom);
youredittext.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

this is the conversion method from pixels to dp and dp to pixels:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public static int pxToDp(int px)
{
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

cheers,

Hamad

Answer (score 1):

this is what I made to show code next to barcode generated by zxing:

```
                        final TextView ticketCodeTV = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.ticketCodeTV);
                        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                        Point size      = new Point();
                        display.getSize(size);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp    = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        lp.rightMargin  = -(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 135, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                        lp.topMargin    = Math.round((size.y / 2) - (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 90, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
                        Log.d("rightMargin", Integer.toString(lp.rightMargin));
                        ticketCodeTV.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        ticketCodeTV.setText(promo.getTicketCode());
```

[image]

add this in layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:paddingLeft="70dp"
        android:paddingRight="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/ticketCodeTV"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```