# Setting Margins for EditText in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've created an AlertDialog with an EditText in my Android app, but the default margins look really off.  I've tried to specify margins as follows:

```
  android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(SpinActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Edit Spin Tags");
            builder.setMessage("(separate tags with commas)");

            // set input
            int margin = 10;
            final EditText input = new EditText(SpinActivity.this);
            input.setSingleLine();
            input.setText(spinTags.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            builder.setView(input, margin, 0, margin, 0);
```

However, from the image below, you can see that it is not applying the desired effect.

[image]

Other options I've tried including placing the input in a LinearLayout and setting the margins using LayoutParams before setting the AlertDialog view to the LinearLayout.

**How do I set the margins for an EditText in an AlertDialog?**

Comment: try the solution from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761611/how-to-set-edittext-topmargins-in-dp-programatically

Comment: @wanpanman just tried this and it had no effect, unfortunately

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually your solution is working perfectly, except that `builder.setView(input, margin, 0, margin, 0);` takes arguments in "pixel" values. So a value of 20 is very small. Either use a higher value for margin e.g. in the 100s. or use this function to convert from dp to pixels

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

and then,

```
int margin = dpToPx(20);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can have a `LinearLayout` as parent of the `EditText`. Then provide the margin to the `EditText`.

```
private void createDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Demo");
    builder.setMessage("Some demo message");
    LinearLayout parentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setHint("Some text");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // call the dimen resource having value in dp: 16dp
    int left = getPixelValue((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin));
    int top = getPixelValue((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin));
    int right = getPixelValue((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin));
    int bottom = getPixelValue((int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin));

    // this will set the margins
    layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

    editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    parentLayout.addView(editText);
    builder.setView(parentLayout);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.create().show();
}

private int getPixelValue(int dp) {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dp, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

For more you can visit http://www.pcsalt.com/android/set-margins-in-dp-programmatically-android/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Define your Edittext in a different layout file while setting proper margins in that layout. Inflate that layout and then set it as view for dialog.