# How do I set margins on a dynamically added EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm attempting to add margins to an EditText that is dynamically created, but for some reason when running the following code nothing happens.

```
public void addName() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

    row = new TableRow(this);
    name = new EditText(this);
    name.setHeight((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textboxHeight));
    name.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textbox));

    counter++;
    row.addView(name, layoutParams);
    namesList.addView(row);
}
```

If I remove the second parameter `layoutParams` from row.addView() it adds the row (without margins), but I want the row to be added with a margin of 15 when dynamically created. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20761703/9725562?

Comment: Yes, I tried that way originally and the same issue occurs